# No matches in fail2ban regex

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I am using fail2ban to try and block any IP that gets multiple failed logins, a failed login is recorded in our application log as "/login.html?success=no".

So I have created a fail2ban .conf, but I can't get it to find any matches, however when I use [this](https://www.debuggex.com/?flavor=python) site, it highlights the line fine. My .conf looks like so:

```
[Definition]

failregex = .*<HOST>.*login\.html\?success=no

ignoreregex =
```

But when I run "fail2ban-regex" to test it, it doesn't find any matches:

```
fail2ban-regex test.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-test.conf

Results

=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total
```

The log file I am using looks like:

```
|  2017/10/03 10:11:53 [error] 14870#14870: *51 access forbidden by rule, client: 1.2.3.4, server: example.com, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
|  2017/10/03 10:11:53 [warn] 14870#14870: *50 delaying request, excess: 0.545, by zone "base", client: 1.2.3.4, server: example.com, request: "GET /login.html?success=no HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

Comment: According to the [fail2ban documentation](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters), the `<HOST>` matched in your log line would be `"GET`. But apart from that, are you sure fail2ban recognizes your timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regex needed to be:

`.*client: <HOST>.*request: "GET \/login\.html\?success=no HTTP/1.1"`

Thanks to @melpomene for pointing me in the right direction, my `<HOST>` wasn't even pointing at the IP.